# How use variable in sed command?

Tags: command-line, scripts, sed

I want to use this command:

```
sed 's/account.db/$PATH/' file1 > file2
```

and

```
sed 's/account.db/$PATH.account.db/' file3 > file4
```

But I dont know how to use it.

Comment: Replace your single quotes with double quotes. (see [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash))

Comment: @Zanna i changed ' by " but it has error

Comment: @Zanna this error:sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to `s'

Comment: You need to use a different delimiter because the PATH contains `/` characters. Do it like this `sed "s#foo#$bar#"` (oops the PATH has colons too!)